# My character won't jump. (Unity2D C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So my code seems to be working just fine. Everything from the animations to gravity to moving works, except for jumping. I can't see what's wrong in my code that wouldn't allow the jumping to work and here's the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class CharacterRun : MonoBehaviour
{

   public float MaxSpeed = 10;
   bool FacingRight = true;
   Animator anim;
   bool grounded = false;
   public Transform groundCheck;
   float groundRadius = 0.2f;
   public LayerMask whatIsGround;
   public float jumpForce = 700f;

   // Use this for initialization
   void Start()
   {
      anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
   }

   // Update is called once per frame
   void FixedUpdate()
   {
       grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);
       anim.SetBool("Ground", grounded);
       anim.SetFloat("vSpeed", GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);

       float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

       anim.SetFloat("hSpeed", Mathf.Abs(move));

       GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(move * MaxSpeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
       GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeRotation;

       if (move > 0 && !FacingRight)
           Flip();
       else if (move < 0 && FacingRight)
           Flip();
   }

   private void SetFloat(string v1, float v2)
   {

   }
   void update ()
   {
       if (grounded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
       {
           anim.SetBool("Ground", false);
           GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
       }

   }
   void Flip()
   {
       FacingRight = !FacingRight;
       Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
       theScale.x *= -1;
       transform.localScale = theScale;
   }
}
```

Comment: My character can still flip even though move = 0. And why would flipping and jumping be the same thing? Have i screwed something up in the code?

Comment: By the looks of it you only call `Flip()` from the if statements, i.e. `move > 0 || move < 0` therefore your character will not `Flip` if `move = 0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you need to name function [Update](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) not update.

```
 void Update ()  /// Not update
 {
       if (grounded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
       {
           anim.SetBool("Ground", false);
           GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
       }
  }
```

Comment: Oh my god I can't believe I actually missed that. Thanks man.